# How to install Intel wireless drivers without the extra bloatware?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, bloatware

How to install just the 7260 WiFi drivers on Windows 7?

I tried unchecking the "Intel ProSet Wireless bloatware" option at the setup stage, and only check the WiFi link driver, but it's still getting installed.
If I uninstall it later from the Add/Remove Programs list it uninstalls the driver too. The computer is Dell Latitude E5540 Notebook.

This is the web page: [Intel 8260 7265 3165 7260 WiFi Driver](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/robsdt1/drivers/DriversDetails?productCode=latitude-e5540-laptop&driverId=YM1PH)

Is there any way to install only the driver without the extra 469 MB of Intel Proset Wireless bloatware?

Comment: Extract the *.inf files from the what I presume is a .msi and use Device Manager to select it as the driver to use for the device.  It is worth pointing out that the "bloatware" is just additional drivers and do not effect performance.

Comment: ok I extracted the windows7 directory with 7zip and inside was a "dpinst". I opened it and now it says installing device drivers but it doesn't stop. It's running for 10 minutes now. And I can't restart either, it stays at "Shutting down" forever

Comment: **I never told you to run an installer.  You didn't follow my suggestion.**  End the process with task manager and restart your computer then follow my instructions.

Comment: i forced shutdown and after starting it again the drivers appear installed now. yey

Answer (score 1):

- Provided Link: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/robsdt1/drivers/DriversDetails?productCode=latitude-e5540-laptop&driverId=YM1PH
- Direct Link (03 Jan 2018): https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER04690673M/1/Intel-8260-7265-3165-7260-WiFi-Driver_YM1PH_WIN_20.10.1.1190_A24.EXE

---

- The file from the direct link is a 32bit executable but actually the file type is a ZIP file. First download [7ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/) (open source) and install it. Then open the driver installer by drag & drop in 7ZIP window. Double click on 'production' folder, choose the Windows OS version (here is Windows 7 64bit), extract the whole "Windows 7-x64" folder <sub><sup>(C:\MyFiles in image)</sup></sub>.

[image: Installer_7ZIP]

- Open Device Manager (devmgmt.msc with Win+R). Right click on the device name. Choose "Update driver" > "Browse my computer" > Enter full folder path <sub><sup>(e.g. C:\MyFiles\Windows 7-x64)</sup></sub> > click on Next. The folder contains .inf, .sys, .cat files. Restart the device to work it properly.

[image: Device_Manager_driver]

Answer (score 0):

> Any way to install the driver only, without the extra 469 MB of Intel
>   Proset wireless bloatware?

Extract the *.inf files from the what I presume is a .msi and use Device Manager to select it as the driver to use for the device. It is worth pointing out, that the "bloatware", should just additional drivers for other Proset wireless devices and does not affect performance.